# Good way to use custom object properties and methods for working with jquery selectors

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#baseRegisterListContainer table thead th[data-isSortable]', function () { ... }
```

And it works fine. But all the functionality of the page I've gathered inside one object:

```
$.BaseRegisterList = function () {
    this.getForm = function () {
        return $('#baseRegisterListForm');
        ...and so on
    }
}
```

How to organize the object to use selector results as well as selector strings like above, only from within this object?
And eliminate hardcoded lines as above within js file?

Comment: there isn't much you can do, other than having `getForm` return a selector instead, or having another method that returns the selector you want.

Comment: Thanks for busting my illusions ;)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following:

```
$.BaseRegisterList = function () {
this.form = '#baseRegisterListForm';
this.table = '#baseRegisterListContainer table';
this.getRows = function () {
    return $(this.table + ' tbody tr');
}
this.moreLinkButton = $(this.table + ' tfoot a').first();
this.sortableColumns = this.table + ' thead th[data-isSortable]';
this.getSortedColumn = function () {
    return $(this.sortableColumns + '[data-sortOrder]').eq(0);
}
//so on
```

So if i need an object instead of string - I just embrace it with $.

Comment: How is it related to event handler?

Comment: Sorry, buddy, i've understood later, that my problem was not as i initially described. So, I've edited my question. Thanks for your input.